# Android: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{/com.}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, exception, google-maps-android-api-2

I created first version of my application using Google Maps Android v1 API. But now When I released my application for second version, Google map stopped working. I think it's because of it's deprecated.

So now I'm trying to create sample Android application to use Google Map using link

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2
```

But I'm getting below force close error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmap/com.example.testmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.example.testmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.testmap-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
... 20 more
```

My Activity code is

```
package com.example.testmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

My xml file code is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testmap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="android.os.Bundle.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCdAP9Sa6lOBZkvn6yOuoEc7JeqM3nPY" />
</application>
```

Please help me, I'm not able to run a simple application using this new Google Map API

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion` in the `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: have you updated you google maps jar file to version 2?

Comment: @Tushar please see my updated question along with manifest code

Comment: @anks there's nothing like jar mentioned on the link, so I haven't included any jar. So is the problem? and then how to solve it?

Comment: this problem is solved, now getting other problem, please help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760834/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable#

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running your code for API level <11, use `FragmentActivity` instead of extending `Activity` and in XML, use `"com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Also check this : **[Google Maps Fragment doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703245/google-maps-fragment-doesnt-load/15703453#15703453)**

Comment: I tried using SupportMapFragment with FragmentActivity, but still force close

Comment: plz see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758303/still-error-android-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo-com-android-view#

Comment: In my case I had to extend MapActivity, and it worked. upvote

Comment: please copy your answer into my question and i accept it as an aswer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235838/binary-xml-file-line-15-error-inflating-class-fragment?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik....
```

It means that it does not find android.view.fragment which has been added in API level 11 (Android 3.0.x, HONEYCOMB); you most likely build for/run on Android 2+

Comment: But he can make use of Android Compatibility package for previous versions