# still error Android: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{/com.}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, exception, google-maps-android-api-2

I created first version of my application using Google Maps Android v1 API. But now When I released my application for second version, Google map stopped working. I think it's because of it's deprecated.

So now I'm trying to create sample Android application to use Google Map using this [**link**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2).

First I was trying with this **[code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757106/android-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo-com-android-view-inflateexce#)**

But as I suggested to use SupportMapFragment with FragmentActivity, I changed my xml code to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and imported FragmentActivity instead of Activity, and now I'm getting error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmap/com.example.testmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.example.testmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
 Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
... 20 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.testmap-2.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
```

Comment: Just a heads up: The _"unable to start activity"_ part is not interesting at all. Ever. The _"Caused by"_ part is. Always.

Comment: refer [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/04/fragments-in-android.html) post for fragment example in android.

Comment: Have you added required libraries - google map libraries and support libs ?

Comment: @DivyaMotiwala  I added them now the problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760834/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable# Please help me

Comment: this problem is solved, please see my updated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760834/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` inside your `<fragment>` tag.

The android:name attribute in the  specifies the Fragment class to instantiate in the layout.

Update:

After you update your code, there is a ClassNotFoundException for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.

So you also need to make sure you added reference library google-play-services.jar.

Comment: please see my updated question, I made changes as you suggested, but still getting error

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed adding id to fragment in navigation xml class.

Add id for this.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.LoginActivity"
        android:label="LoginActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_login"/>
```

Adding id removed the error:

```
<activity
        android:id="@+id/loginActivity"
        android:name="com.example.LoginActivity"
        android:label="LoginActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_login"/>
```

When I removed unused resources the id of login activity got removed. Make sure while cleaning up you won't remove the necessary id's.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by changing emulator or device , I overcame from this error.