# android : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, exception, google-maps-android-api-2

My activity code

```
package com.example.testmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

xml file code

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="android.os.Bundle.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY_FROM_GOOGLE_API_CONSOLE" />
</application>
```

but I'm getting error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.example.testmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** Try to remove this line:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

from the fragment in the XML file, it shouldn't be there.

**2.** Change this permission:

```
<permission
android:name="android.os.Bundle.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

to this:

```
<permission
android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

if `com.example.mapdemo` is your project package.
if not change it to your project package in this permission and this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Great @androiddeveloper, have a nice coding : )

Answer (score 2):

Have you copied google-play-services.jar instead of linking to google-play-services_lib project?

Follow this carefully: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Answer (score 0):

try importing the project from android sdk:
**/extras/google/google_play_services_libproject/google_play_services_lib**
 into your workspace whithout add anyone lib in folder /lib at your app.

after do this, add them in your: **project>properties>android>libs add**

Comment: Are you using an fragment or activity?