# Android Google Map Version 2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been working from past hours to get Google map work but it seems like I am doing some thing wrong ..

Let me share some information with you ..

Here's my work ..

MainActivity.java class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            double latitude = 17.385044;
            double longitude = 78.486671;

            // lets place some 10 random markers
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                // random latitude and logitude
                double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                        longitude);

                // Adding a marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .title("Hello Maps " + i);

                Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", "
                        + randomLocation[1]);

                // changing marker color
                if (i == 0)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                if (i == 1)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                if (i == 2)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
                if (i == 3)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                if (i == 4)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                if (i == 5)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                if (i == 6)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                if (i == 7)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                if (i == 8)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
                if (i == 9)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
                if (i == 9) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                    randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }
}
```

Here's my XMl file ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's my Manifest file ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBZMlkOv4sj-M5JO9p6wksdax4TEjDVLgo" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am fallowing AndroidHive tutorial < http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ >

Error what I am getting ..

My Error log ::

```
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     ... 11 more
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2-2.apk]
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-24 13:32:56.062: E/AndroidRuntime(7014):     ... 20 more
```

I have fallowed each and every part in tutorial . Also I have consulted other sites including Google itself.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated .. Let me know if I need to put some thing more than that.

Thanks!

Comment: give name to fragment. like android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"

Comment: is google_play_services library added?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235838/binary-xml-file-line-15-error-inflating-class-fragment/18307228#18307228

Comment: @AndroidHacker: Please let me know if that worked or not.

Comment: @user1728071 .. That didn't worked ..

Comment: @AndroidHacker: Did you copy and pasted the code in Fragment?

Comment: @deniz... I have included lib for same.

Comment: @AndroidHacker: Do not copy and paste the code I commented. write the package path of your activity.java file inside <frament>. if the activity.java file you are implementing the fragment is in package "info.androidhive.googlemapsv2" then you have to write "android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity" inside fragment.

Comment: @AndroidHacker: Also instead of extending activity. extend android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.

Comment: @user1728071 yes I did that way too ... But with no sucess

Comment: @AndroidHacker : Use SupportMapFragment, check my answer

Comment: @user1728071 nope I used my package name .. Can U post your xml please ..

Comment: @AndroidHacker: Refer to the code, I have answered. First try to get the map. Then you can move with the rest of the stuffs.

Comment: change ur `android:minSdkVersion="9"` to `android:minSdkVersion="12"` otherwise u need to use `FragmentActivity` and `SupportFragment`

Comment: @kaushik No sucess with that ..

Comment: @kaushik I still facing Force Close problem ..

Comment: @AndroidHacker : have u checked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the google play services library and `android-support-v4` library for the support map fragments.

[image]

[image]

Also in your `InitializeMap()` method as you are using the `SupportMapFragment` same way you need to initialize your map with `SupportMapFragment` only not with `MapFragment`. Change your code as below:

```
  private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**

In your `MainActivity` besides extending `Activity` try to extends `FragmentActivity` as below

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

Comment: Yes I did like that also .. No sucess

Comment: Have you changed initialization of your map in your `initilizeMap()` method as i have shown ?

Comment: @AndroidHacker Also you are calling `initilizeMap()` two times one in `onCreate()` and second in `onResume()` which in not required. Either you call it in `onCreate()` or `onResume()`.

Comment: Do not extends Activity in your class. You need to extends `FragmentActivity` check out my updated answer @AndroidHacker

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.**SupportMapFragment**" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your xml you arer using `SupportMapFragment` but in code you are using `getFragmentManager()` you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) `getSupportFragmentManager`().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using same only .. to get support but with no sucess

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project select `Android Tools -> Add Support Library` to add the Support Libraries to your project

and in your activity change the `Activity` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity{
```

and change your initialization to this

```
if (googleMap == null) {
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

Add this import also

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Comment: I think there's problem in my xml file or manifest file .. I am doing same way as U are suggesting

Comment: I am also using SupportMapFragment

Comment: @AndroidHacker: The code you posted here is differen, your activity is extending the `Activity` not `FragmentActivity `, The XML seems fine

Comment: @AndroidHacker : The XML is correct check here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

Comment: @AndroidHacker : You logcat shows `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment` its Fragment which is supported from API 11 and greater not SupportFragment.Do one thing remove all the code in onCreate and just leave it empty see if map is displaying or not

Comment: @AndroidHacker : Can you upload you project and send the link. Let me try

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43814/discussion-between-androidhacker-and-girish-nair)

Answer (score 0):

I felt the same problem when I did. But after that it worked for me. Check my code for showing the Map. Once you get the map, you can proceed with the next step.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAP8K9rStcxbXNO7jRD_FhzDiNbB8AWEwA"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change in your layout

> class="com.google.android.maps.SupportMapFragment"
>   to
>   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

1. You need to define this in your mainfest file under application tag

   ```
   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name">

   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

   <activity
       android:name="com.example.androidhackergooglemap.MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <!-- Goolge API Key -->
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="AIzaSyCv_j5f8gEkjjtU0BLPaLsz1iWzIOyUCBg" />
   ```